# Tracking event completion based on page referral

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a question about trying to get some detailed information around specific event completion. I'm wondering if it is possible within Google Analytics to track event completion within a specific Category but with different Actions?

I have a group of pages (`A` which can be matched with a simple regex) and these page have linked content (with an event on it) that can funnel users to another page (`B`) where I have an action I want to track (form completion essentially). What is the best way to set up a goal or flow to see how many people from pages `A` complete the action on page `B`.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you have the Events Flow report, under Behaviour-->Events.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to apply a "Segment" to your events report that shows only the events for a specific set of users.   A segment is Google's term for a report filter.   To do so:

1. View the report you are intersted in
2. Click "+ Add Segment"
3. Click "+ New Segment"
4. Use "Advanced" ->  "Conditions"
5. Use "Filter sessions include page matches regex"
6. Enter your regular expression
7. Save the segment
8. Make sure that only that segment is applied (you may have to remove "all sessions")